# VS 2015 Express not discovering/or buggy built in Unit Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

my problem is that VS 2015 Express doesn't discover/are buggy the Unit Tests that are built in VS, my code looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class Service1Test
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void Test1()
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Dunno why but VS doesn't discover even this basic Unit Test,nor other ones, interestingly if I let the PC for about 5-10 mins VS finally discover the Unit Tests :

[image: After 5-10 min]

Also if I try to run it I have to wait another 5 to 10 mins just to run this very basic Unit Test, here is a gift to show what I'm talking about :

[GIF Buggy Unit Testing](https://giphy.com/gifs/l0Iy6YRszqsz6720M)

And finally after 5-10 mins the unit test is done: 
[image]

Can anyone help me? Why does VS behaves like this? At this pace currently I cant work, thanks.

> EDIT: Even when I don't nest Test Classes VS doesn't run my Unit Tests

Comment: why are you nesting test classes?  That's almost certainly not a good idea.

Comment: Even when I don't nest test classes VS doesn't run my Unit Tests

Comment: What happens if you change your project from a console application to a class library?

Comment: @DavidL [GIF Class Library](http://giphy.com/gifs/3oKIP6lKlyf6D1AByw) its basically the same, dunno why but in my laptop its works flawlessly, but in my work VS is really buggy